# Cannot access POST route in Laravel via browser

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes, http-post

Using Laravel 5.4 have this route in web.php

```
Route::post('foo/bar', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

but when I visit the http://localhost:8000/foo/bar URL in browser I have this error:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 251: in
>   RouteCollection.php line 251 at
>   RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in
>   RouteCollection.php line 238 at
>   RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST')) in
>   RouteCollection.php line 176 at
>   RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 533 ...

I want to test a POST route method via the browser.

Comment: Use some sort of test extension. I use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) on Chrome and it works (not 100% happy with it but it gets the job done). Alternatively you could use cURL on the Laravel built-in testing tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it

```
Route::post(
```

to

```
Route::get(
```

and try again.

**Explanation:** `Route::post()` is used when we want to post the form with some data in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::get('foo/bar', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

use this as you are not posting any data thus laravel is looking for data which is not present thus the error