# Deploying laravel api rest on ubuntu and nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-5

I have a REST API with Laravel 5.5 LTS that I want to deploy to my ubuntu server and use nginx.

I have uploaded the api to my ubuntu server and the updated my nginx config file like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /myservername/api/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name myservername.com www.myservername.com;
        location /api {
                try_files $uri/ /server.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass             unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```

I then have an endpoint route configured as:

```
Route::get('/api/mail/send', 'MailController@index');
```

now when I go to myservername.com/api/mail/send I get a 404 not found.

The MailController just does a var_dump():

```
class MailController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function index(Request $request) {
        var_dump('hi');
    } }
```

Anyone know what I am missing? My second location block I basically copy pasted, do i need it? as I notice that unix path does not exist (/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock)

Comment: You should not be able to hit this route with your browser, as the browser is using `GET`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43845836/823549. As you are not posting, a 404 makes sense here.

Comment: i updated the question with a new get route and that does the same thing

Comment: Ah okay! Can you please update the question with the contents of your associated routes file and `MailController`?

Comment: the MailController simply does a var_dump('hi');. Also updated the question to show that

Comment: Pretty sure I know the issue! Change the index function in MailController to public

Comment: Did that and it made no difference, still a 404